# IIS throws 404 error for aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a website which is on .NET 4.0 pool.

Overnight after deploying the code, I'll test the site and IIS will serve it fine. But the very next day it stops serving the aspx pages and throws 404 error.

The files are all present. The static resources are still served.

So everytime, if I just fire iisreset then the website starts serving the pages again.

Any clue what's going wrong here?

Comment: We have a very similar issue with one of our pages. Does it happen to be using Microsoft charts?

Comment: try re-register ASP.NET e.g. `aspnet_regiis -i -enable`

Comment: First step: Look in the Windows Event Log.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are some sites using the same pool and one of them caused issue that effected other. I would suggest:

1. Look at the Windows Event Log for real issue
2. Create new application pool and use it for your site.

Comment: I looked at the event logs and there are no errors logged. So everything looks fine. The prod website is running on separate app pool so that's not a problem.